# Flag qualifying rows for the next X number of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where items are flagged when they meet certain criteria. So, every time you see a date in the qualifying_date column, that means the item met the criteria on that day and was therefore flagged:

```
        current_date   abc    xyz    rth    qualifying_date
index
apple   2015-01-27     23     5712   713    
        2015-01-28     234    1357   152    2015-01-28
        2015-01-29     489    185    278
        2015-01-30     154    951    754
pear    2015-01-27     4786   7531   4751
        2015-01-28     476    367    45
        2015-01-29     15     37     783    2015-01-29
        2015-01-30     489    185    421
grape   2015-01-27     2513   57     7513   2015-01-27
        2015-01-28     237    587    733
        2015-01-29     7869   472    759    2015-01-29
        2015-01-30     489    185    278
```

Now I need to populate every row of the dataframe to indicate when each item last qualified. In other words, if a certain item meets the criteria on 2015-01-27, it is flagged on that day. But then every day after that needs to have that same date filled in because it is the most recent time that item qualifed. That continues until the item has a new qualifying date (ie: meets the criteria again). The output would look as follows:

```
        current_date   abc    xyz    rth    qualifying_date
index
apple   2015-01-27     23     5712   713    
        2015-01-28     234    1357   152    2015-01-28
        2015-01-29     489    185    278    2015-01-28
        2015-01-30     154    951    754    2015-01-28
pear    2015-01-27     4786   7531   4751   
        2015-01-28     476    367    45     
        2015-01-29     15     37     783    2015-01-29
        2015-01-30     489    185    421    2015-01-29
grape   2015-01-27     2513   57     7513   2015-01-27
        2015-01-28     237    587    733    2015-01-27
        2015-01-29     7869   472    759    2015-01-29
        2015-01-30     489    185    278    2015-01-29
```

Obviously if an item has never qualified, then the qualifying_date column will be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to group by each index value, then you can use `fillna(method='pad')` to fill in the missing values downwards:

```
df.groupby('index').qualifying_date.fillna(method='pad')
Out[91]: 
0            NaN
1            NaN
2     2015-01-28
3     2015-01-28
4     2015-01-28
5            NaN
6            NaN
7     2015-01-29
8     2015-01-29
9     2015-01-27
10    2015-01-27
11    2015-01-29
12    2015-01-29
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def fill_date(df):
    df.qualifying_date.fillna(method='ffill' , inplace=True)
    return df.reset_index(drop = True)

df.groupby(df.index).apply(fill_date)
```

[image]